# How can I create a slanted divider for a row on my wordpress website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Example : https://gyazo.com/9d7c3a9fcbf79481b60c8686eb15adc8

Part I want to adjust : https://gyazo.com/8ad686c3ca19ce64c2693042102dee04

Comment: https://codepen.io/erikdkennedy/pen/pRVbzx

Answer (score 1):

Building on Gerard's answer:
Add the following into your wordpress theme's styles.css (or similar)
(Add a class to the H1 if you dont want all H1s turning into the below)

```
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ff9d2f, #ff6126);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0;
  font: 44px "Arial";
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  color: white;
}

.divider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  /* drop the height to have a constant angle for all screen widths */
}
```

Then this goes into the page itself, remember to save the divider triangle image locally

```
<header>
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
  <img src="http://erikdkennedy.com/r-r-r-random/divider-triangle.png" class="divider" />
</header>

<section>
  <h1>Section Content</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work : ( this is what happened when I tested the method https://gyazo.com/d4fce426aca4df277721d831cbed77a9